# Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped) Gtkmm

Tags: c++, gtkmm, coredump

**This Is HomeWork**

Hey im using Gtkmm for an Assignment and i have been doing well with it all and all however im getting an odd problem in a function i use to fill a TreeView u get the error

(out:21185): GLib-ERROR **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.32.3/./glib/gmem.c:408: overflow allocating 3908326912*4 bytes
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

the odd part however is that i use this function for 3 separate TreeViews and it is only on my most recent i have written i get this error

i have isolated the problem to the line

```
*m_refTreeModel = Gtk::ListStore::create((*m_columns));
```

any ideas of how this could be happening? my program is rather large so showing all the source code related to this would be difficult to upload. however here is the function this line is in

Controller.cpp

```
#include "Controller.h"
#include "ModelColumns.h"
#include <iostream>

Controller::Controller()
{
    mainMenue = (MainMenueView*) new MainMenueView(this);
    studentMenue = (StudentMenueView*) new StudentMenueView(this);
    degreeMenue = (DegreeMenueView*) new DegreeMenueView(this);
    underGradView = (UnderGradView*) new UnderGradView(this);
    workExpView = (WorkExpView*) new WorkExpView(this);
    relatedCourseView = (RelatedCourseView*) new RelatedCourseView(this);
    tAExpView = (TAExpView*) new TAExpView(this);
    referencesView = (ReferencesView*) new ReferencesView(this);
    gradView = (GradView*) new GradView(this);
    adminMenueView = (AdminMenueView*) new AdminMenueView(this);
    viewPendingAppsMenue = (ViewPendingAppsMenue*) new ViewPendingAppsMenue(this);
    pendingAppsView = (PendingAppsView*) new PendingAppsView(this);
    assignMenueView = (AssignMenueView*) new AssignMenueView(this);
    assignSuccessView = (AssignSuccessView*) new AssignSuccessView(this);
    editLoginView = (EditLoginView*) new EditLoginView(this);
    editAppView = (EditAppView*) new EditAppView(this);

    //Setting up the window
    set_title("");
    set_border_width(10);
    set_default_size(700,400);

    //setting up the notebook
    gui.set_border_width(10);
    gui.set_show_tabs(false);
    add(gui);

    gui.append_page((*mainMenue));
    gui.append_page((*studentMenue));
    gui.append_page((*degreeMenue));
    gui.append_page((*underGradView));
    gui.append_page((*workExpView));
    gui.append_page((*relatedCourseView));
    gui.append_page((*tAExpView));
    gui.append_page((*referencesView));
    gui.append_page((*gradView));
    gui.append_page((*adminMenueView));
    gui.append_page((*viewPendingAppsMenue));
    gui.append_page((*pendingAppsView));
    gui.append_page((*assignMenueView));
    gui.append_page((*assignSuccessView));
    gui.append_page((*editLoginView));  
    gui.append_page((*editAppView));
    show_all_children();

}



Controller::~Controller()
{
delete mainMenue;
delete studentMenue;
delete degreeMenue;
delete underGradView;
delete workExpView;
delete relatedCourseView;
delete tAExpView;
delete referencesView;
delete gradView;
delete adminMenueView;
delete viewPendingAppsMenue;
delete pendingAppsView;
delete assignMenueView;
delete assignSuccessView;
}

void Controller::fillTreeModel(const Glib::ustring &page, const Glib::ustring &type, const Glib::ustring type1)
{
ModelColumns *m_columns;
Gtk::TreeView *m_TreeView;
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::ListStore> *m_refTreeModel;
std::string temp;
int tempNum;

if (page == "Pending")
{
    m_columns = &(pendingAppsView -> m_columns);
    m_TreeView = &(pendingAppsView -> m_TreeView);
    m_refTreeModel = &(pendingAppsView -> m_refTreeModel);
}
else if (page == "Assign")
{
    m_columns = &(assignSuccessView -> m_columns);
    m_TreeView = &(assignSuccessView -> m_TreeView);
    m_refTreeModel = &(assignSuccessView -> m_refTreeModel);
}
else if (page == "Edit")
{
    m_columns = &(editAppView -> m_columns);
    m_TreeView = &(editAppView -> m_TreeView);
    m_refTreeModel = &(editAppView -> m_refTreeModel);
}



if (type1 == "Pending")
{
    temp = "Pending";
}
if (type1 == "Student")
{
    tempNum = stuNumHold;
}
else
{
    temp = "";
}


//setting up the next page's treeView
if (type == "View All")
{
    model.pendingApps.fillGrads(temp);
    model.pendingApps.fillUnderGrads(temp);
}
else if (type == "Student")
{
    model.pendingApps.fillGrads(tempNum);
    model.pendingApps.fillUnderGrads(tempNum);
//std::cout << "here4" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::string tbCourse = Glib::locale_from_utf8(type);
    model.pendingApps.fillGrads(&tbCourse, temp);
    model.pendingApps.fillUnderGrads(&tbCourse, temp);
}

     //std::cout << model.pendingApps.underGrads[0].getStuNum() << "***" << std::endl;

*m_refTreeModel = Gtk::ListStore::create((*m_columns));

    //std::cout << model.pendingApps.underGrads[0].getStuNum() << "***" << std::endl;

(*m_TreeView).set_model((*m_refTreeModel));
Gtk::TreeModel::Row row;

   //std::cout << model.pendingApps.underGrads[0].getStuNum() << "***" << std::endl;

while (model.pendingApps.grads.front() != NULL || model.pendingApps.underGrads.front() != NULL)
{
//std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
    Grad *tempGrad = model.pendingApps.grads.front();
    UnderGrad *tempUnderGrad = model.pendingApps.underGrads.front();

    std::string temp1, temp2;
    if (model.pendingApps.grads.front() != NULL)
    {
        temp1 = (*tempGrad).getCourse();
    }
    if (model.pendingApps.underGrads.front() != NULL)
    {
        temp2 = (*tempUnderGrad).getCourse();
    }

    if (model.pendingApps.underGrads.front() != NULL && type == "View All" && (tempGrad == NULL || strcmp(temp1.c_str(), temp2.c_str()) > 0))
    {
        row = *((*m_refTreeModel) -> append());
        row [m_columns -> m_col_appNum] = (*tempUnderGrad).getAppNum();
        row [m_columns -> m_col_degree] = "Undergraduate";
        row [m_columns -> m_col_course] = (*tempUnderGrad).getCourse(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_first] = (*tempUnderGrad).getFName(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_last] = (*tempUnderGrad).getLName(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_email] = (*tempUnderGrad).getEmail(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_major] = (*tempUnderGrad).getMajor(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_field] = ""; 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_sup] = ""; 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_stuNum] = (*tempUnderGrad).getStuNum(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_year] = (*tempUnderGrad).getYear(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_gpa] = (*tempUnderGrad).getGPA(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_cGPA] = (*tempUnderGrad).getCGPA();
        row [m_columns -> m_col_app_status] = (*tempUnderGrad).getAppStatus();
        model.pendingApps.underGrads.popFront();


    }
    else if (model.pendingApps.grads.front() != NULL && type == "View All" && (tempUnderGrad == NULL || strcmp(temp1.c_str(), temp2.c_str()) <= 0))
    {
        row = *((*m_refTreeModel) -> append());
        row [m_columns -> m_col_appNum] = (*tempGrad).getAppNum();
        row [m_columns -> m_col_degree] = "Graduate";
        row [m_columns -> m_col_course] = (*tempGrad).getCourse(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_first] = (*tempGrad).getFName(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_last] = (*tempGrad).getLName(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_email] = (*tempGrad).getEmail(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_field] = (*tempGrad).getResearch(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_sup] = (*tempGrad).getSupervisor();
        row [m_columns -> m_col_stuNum] = (*tempGrad).getStuNum(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_app_status] = (*tempGrad).getAppStatus();

        model.pendingApps.grads.popFront();
    }
    else if (model.pendingApps.underGrads.front() != NULL && model.pendingApps.grads.front() != NULL && type != "View All")
    {
        row = *((*m_refTreeModel) -> append());
        row [m_columns -> m_col_appNum] = (*tempGrad).getAppNum();
        row [m_columns -> m_col_degree] = "Graduate";
        row [m_columns -> m_col_course] = (*tempGrad).getCourse(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_first] = (*tempGrad).getFName(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_last] = (*tempGrad).getLName(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_email] = (*tempGrad).getEmail(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_field] = (*tempGrad).getResearch(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_sup] = (*tempGrad).getSupervisor();
        row [m_columns -> m_col_stuNum] = (*tempGrad).getStuNum(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_app_status] = (*tempGrad).getAppStatus();

        model.pendingApps.grads.popFront();
    }
    else
    {

        row = *((*m_refTreeModel) -> append());
        row [m_columns -> m_col_appNum] = (*tempUnderGrad).getAppNum();
        row [m_columns -> m_col_degree] = "Undergraduate";
        row [m_columns -> m_col_course] = (*tempUnderGrad).getCourse(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_first] = (*tempUnderGrad).getFName(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_last] = (*tempUnderGrad).getLName(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_email] = (*tempUnderGrad).getEmail(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_major] = (*tempUnderGrad).getMajor(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_field] = ""; 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_sup] = ""; 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_stuNum] = (*tempUnderGrad).getStuNum(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_year] = (*tempUnderGrad).getYear(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_gpa] = (*tempUnderGrad).getGPA(); 
        row [m_columns -> m_col_cGPA] = (*tempUnderGrad).getCGPA();
        row [m_columns -> m_col_app_status] = (*tempUnderGrad).getAppStatus();
        model.pendingApps.underGrads.popFront();
    }
}


}
```

Controller.h

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_H
#define CONTROLLER_H

#include <gtkmm.h>

#include "MainMenueView.h"
#include "StudentMenueView.h"
#include "DegreeMenueView.h"
#include "UnderGradView.h"
#include "WorkExpView.h"
#include "RelatedCourseView.h"
#include "TAExpView.h"
#include "ReferencesView.h"
#include "GradView.h"
#include "AdminMenueView.h"
#include "ViewPendingAppsMenue.h"
#include "PendingAppsView.h"
#include "Model.h"
#include "AssignMenueView.h"
#include "AssignSuccessView.h"
#include "EditAppView.h"
#include "EditLoginView.h"

class MainMenueView;
class StudentMenueView;
class DegreeMenueView;
class UnderGradView;
class WorkExpView;
class RelatedCourseView;
class TAExpView;
class ReferencesView;
class GradView;
class AdminMenueView;
class ViewPendingAppsMenue;
class PendingAppsView;
class AssignMenueView;
class AssignSuccessView;
class EditAppView;
class EditLoginView;

 class Controller : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    Controller();
    virtual ~Controller();
    Gtk::Notebook gui;
    int appNumber, stuNumHold;
    Glib::ustring degreeLevel, courseApplied, searchType;
    Glib::ustring studentMode;

    void fillTreeModel(const Glib::ustring&, const Glib::ustring&, const Glib::ustring);

    Model model;
private:
    MainMenueView *mainMenue; //0
    StudentMenueView *studentMenue; //1
    DegreeMenueView *degreeMenue; //2
    UnderGradView *underGradView; //3
    WorkExpView *workExpView; //4
    RelatedCourseView *relatedCourseView; //5
    TAExpView *tAExpView; //6
    ReferencesView *referencesView;  //7
    GradView *gradView; //8
    AdminMenueView *adminMenueView; //9
    ViewPendingAppsMenue *viewPendingAppsMenue; //10
    PendingAppsView *pendingAppsView; //11
    AssignMenueView *assignMenueView; //12
    AssignSuccessView *assignSuccessView; //13
    EditLoginView *editLoginView; //14
    EditAppView *editAppView; //15
};

#endif
```

Comment: `3908326912*4 bytes` is a rather large number. Are you sure you intended to allocate this much memory?

Comment: yeah that is alot of memory lol no that is not intended lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Controller::fillTreeModel(const Glib::ustring &, const Glib::ustring &, const Glib::ustring)`, if `page` is not one of "Pending", "Assign", or "Edit", `m_Columns` will never be initialized. I have not looked at all the code because it is rather long, but this is most likely the issue if `3908326912` was unintended (I'm not sure what a `ModelColumns` is though).

I suggest you have a default case which either assigns a default fallback value or throws an exception.

Comment: awsome thanks, i was tightly controlling the input into the function, however it appears i made a slip somewhere, the base case helps alot thanks!